# Purple haze displaying from power on

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I had the computer hooked up to a 23" LG monitor via DVI and everything was fine. Then I hooked it up to a 27" Dell U2713HM via the same DVI and I get this crazy purple haze over the screen. I did try changing cables and that didn't work.

Everything acts fine though. It doesn't crash or freeze, it's just this ugly purple haze that's always on the screen, from the time that when I power on.

Where do I start trying to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a software issue. It could very well be a problem with your display. I would suggest connecting another computer to the same display. If the problem persists, there's something wrong with the display.

If the display does work fine with another computer you should try booting a completely different OS to determine if the problem is in software or hardware.

Comment: Thanks. I can hook up my MacBook Pro via Display Port to the display and it will be perfect.